# Creating an object using Reflection: Activator.CreateInstance or Inovking the constructor C#

Tags: .net

Which is the better way to create an object using reflection?

Getting a reference of the constructor and invoking the constructor to create the object or

Using `Activator.CreateInstance` on the Type of the class.

Better in the sense are there any specific reasons why we would opt for one method over the other? If so in what cases.

I am just learning reflection and had this question.

Comment: Define "better" here :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They do the same thing. It's just easier to use [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx).

> Creates an instance of the specified type using the constructor that
>   best matches the specified parameters.

Actually, you may net some performance benefit from using `Activator` since it caches constructor instances internally. If you are creating many of these in a loop, there is a good chance the Activator code is simply more optimized than a naive hand rolled implementation.